# Java graphic.drawImage not appearing

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have a loaded image, but when I try to display it nothing is appearing.

```
public class JComponentButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

BufferedImage image;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test Title3");
    mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){ 
          System.exit(0);
       }        
    }); 

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JComponentButton button = new JComponentButton();
    button.setSize(64,64);
    controlPanel.add(button);

    mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("finishing");
}

public JComponentButton(){
    super();
    try {
        this.image = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/default.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("did not load image");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    enableInputMethods(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println(image.getHeight() + "," + image.getWidth());
    g.drawImage(image, 64, 64, null);
}
```

The image seems to be loaded as 64,64 is printed into the console. However where it should be appearing on the window is blank. I drew a square there without a problem using g.fillRect. So it seems like the problem has to be with g.drawImage. I also tried changing the perspective from null to this, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the method `g.drawImage(image, 64, 64, null)` will draw your image at it's full resolution **starting at the offset at 64, 64**.

Javadoc for drawImage:

> Draws as much of the specified image as is currently available. The image is drawn with its top-left corner at (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate space. Transparent pixels in the image do not affect whatever pixels are already there.

This means that whilst your image is indeed being drawn, it's being drawn outside the visible co-ordinate space of your button.

To fix the issue, replace the `64, 64` with `0, 0` if the image is sized at the component's size or use the more explicit method `drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)` to specify what the image should be resized to whilst in the button.

E.g.

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); //draws image at full resolution

g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 64, 64, null); //draws image at offset 0, for max resolution of 64x64
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Zachac Don't forget to accept an answer if you deem it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't view the image is because the image is drawn outside of the button.
since you don't have any panel outside the button,it cannot be drawn.

The reason is,the x and y axis of the image that you have specified,i.e.Top left corner,are 64,64 and the button is of size 64,64.Thus,this image will be drawn at bottom right of the button,that is the corner point of the button.
Thus you should specify image points as 0,0 (these are the top-left corner of image) so that it will cover the 0,0(these are the top-left corner of button)  point of the button.

Also,you must specify the width and height of the image.So,that it will not go out side of bounds of button.If you don't want to specify the width and height then you must decrease the pixels of the image to the size of button(at least).

you can rewrite the code as:
`g.drawImage(image,0,0,64,64,null);`